# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "AND": syntax error. Только начал изучать sqlite3. Помогите(

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def database():

db = sqlite3.connect('Chromedexser.db')
sql = db.cursor()

sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    login TEXT,
    surname TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    city TEXT,
    birthday TEXT
    )""")

db.commit()


sql.execute(f'SELECT login, password FROM users WHERE login = {namebase} AND password = {passowrdbase}')

if sql.fetchone() is None :
    sql.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (namebase, surnamebase, birthdaybase, citybase, passowrdbase))
    print('Добро пожаловать')
    db.commit()

else:
    print('Такая запись уже есть')
```

Comment: Попробуй записать так - sql.execute('SELECT login, password FROM users WHERE login = ? AND password = ?', (namebase, passowrdbase)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Всё заработало